# iPod Touch /w iOS4 - Why do I have to have iTunes installed to charge?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, charging

Do I have to have iTunes running to charge my iPod Touch?  I mean, can't I just turn on my computer and have the USB port just charge the silly thing?  All my other devices work like that; why does Apple have to be such a prima-donna?

Comment: Oh wait a minute, nevermind, I just had it plugged into the USB hub, you don't need iTunes or anything... :-p

Still for $300 the least Jobs could do is give me a longer USB cable.

Comment: Another point here: USB ports can run in either low-power or high-power mode and obviously you want the high power mode to charge your device quicker. However your machine won't necessarily switch the port to high-power mode unless it recognises the device, which usually means installing the drivers, which usually means installing iTunes. Some PCs and hubs will run some ports in high-power mode regardless, though, and you'll be able to use these to charge your device without software. But usable third-party wall-socket chargers are pretty cheap too.

Answer (score 3):

You pretty much self-answered the question but, in any case and for future reference:

You don’t need iTunes to charge iPhones/Pads/Pods. iPhones come with a wall-pluggable charger that also happens to charge the other members of the family.